# How to get a transcript of an audio or video call within a js web app? I.e. how to route a MediaStream to a speech-to-text API

Tags: javascript, web-applications, speech-to-text, peerjs, mediastream

I want to make a web-app which does video calls with live transcription -- using some 3rd party speech-to-text service (e.g. Google or Amazon). So the peer-to-peer MediaStream would be played to the users, and also sent to the API for transcription.

I am currently using https://peerjs.com/ to create the peer-to-peer call.

Is this feasible? Are there any code examples or libraries I could use?

Thank you, Daniel

Comment: Something like [this](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#speech-streaming-recognize-nodejs) but for web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it can easily be done with
[Azure speach to text service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-GB/services/cognitive-services/speech-to-text/), Perhaps other solutions may be used, but for Azure I was able to quickly find all pieces.

There is browser use case example [Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/js/browser)

[This line](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/054b4783de9d52f28109c435bf90e073513fec97/samples/js/browser/index.html#L537) is responsible for getting audio source from microphone, but in you case more interesting would be to use: [fromStreamInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/audioconfig?view=azure-node-latest#fromStreamInput_AudioInputStream___PullAudioInputStreamCallback___MediaStream_) function, which accepts MediaStream.

I’m also wondering what would be better place to execute this process:

- on source machine, send audio to receiver and to speachSDK, and after getting transcription send it afterwards.
- on receiver machine, after receiving use SDK to get transcription, in this case audio may have worse quality as it was compressed during transmission, therefore you may get worse transcription.

However this can be easily be tested.

Comment: That looks great - except I think it runs server-side. The browser example has a required server hosting part.

Comment: This `php` file in the example is misleading, see requirements: `Optionally, a web server that supports hosting PHP scripts.` 
It is used only for generating token used to access SpeachSDK, see this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/js/browser/index.html#L260

It is not wise to have such token on browser side, someone would be able to steal it and use service on your bill.